Let a third-party upload any file to a s3 storage via curl without having to compute a signature
So the issue I'm having is that I want a third-party to be able to upload any file to a s3 storage with a token as my third-party only have access to curl not any aws sdk.
I've been able to achieve that by providing the third-party a signing key and my access key. User can upload by computing a signature from this signing key and calling PUT on my storage following this documentation.
The problem is that third-party has to redo some of those steps each time he wants to upload something (recomputing the signature with current date) which I would like to avoid.
In Azure you can provide a pre-signed url for the container you want to upload to meaning that you can provide this url to a third-party for it to upload without having to do any other operation, is there a similar way to do that on aws without forcing a user to do extra steps such as computing a signature ?
I saw that there is this concept of pre-signed url for aws but this seems to be only for specific files. I'm looking for similar concepts but for whole bucket

As you noted, S3 pre-signed URLs are per-object. While not completely trivial to implement or use, you could create a simple pre-upload API (e.g. using API Gateway and Lambda) that vends pre-signed URLs for a given client request.

I understand but I would like the third-party to perform the upload directly to s3 without having to pass through another api. The whole purpose of this is that client request once a "token" that he can save on his side and use it until its expiration to perform upload of various file (saving calls to an external api that would send it a pre-signed url as you suggested). Clients can already do this for Azure uploads and I'm surprised there's not an equivalent of this for s3...

While I agree that this would be a useful feature for S3, it isn't supported natively right now.
